# How to Build Android API Level 29 In Unity 2018

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, game-engine

I'm using Unity 2018.3 and recently I tried to build an `apk` to share on google play, but it seems like google play does not support the apps with API level under 29.

And on the other hand, the maximum API level in unity 2018 is 28!

I searched over the internet but I do not found a solution for this issue.

I want to know is there any way to add API level 29 to unity 2018? (Without upgrade unity to newer versions)

Comment: API 29 is working from 2018.4, which version of 2018 are you using?

Comment: I said, 2018.3.9. but I installed 2018.4.23 but I didn't see API 29 . @Lotan

Comment: you didn't see or when you select API 29 on settings Unity says that you need to install It through SDK manager?

Answer (score 0):

https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-api-level-29.945251/#post-6164172

> I ran the sdkmager.bat on a Windows console (as administrator) located
> in C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.6f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\bin.
> The typed command was sdkmanager "platform-tools"
> "platforms;android-29" "build-tools;29.0.3" and API level 29 got
> installed. Unity built the android app normally.
>
> For more info about running the sdkmanager
> https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager
>
> The error for update on Unity seems to be related with administrator
> permissions for file writing on Windows.
> -jumadiazgranados

Newer version of Unity (2019 and newer) has the option to build API 29 without having to do the above

Other existing answer:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-sdk-29-unable-to-install-additional-sdk-platform-issue-workaround.963626/#post-6390657

djweaver:

> What I and a few others have done is copy the android 29 sdk directly
> into the folder that unity looks in for sdks.
>
> 1. Make sure you have the android 29 SDK: Open Android Studio. After
>    the splash screen has loaded, select the Configure button (bottom
>    right, next to gear icon) and from the dropdown select SDK Manager and
>    in the list make sure Android 10 (API 29) is checked, if it isn't
>    check it and apply to download the SDK.
> 2. Get the path to the Android SDK directory From the same window,
>    note the path in the text field labeled Android SDK Location
> 3. Get the path to Unity's Android SDK directory In Unity, click Edit
>    => Preferences => External Tools. Scroll down and find a list of text fields with paths under the Android label. Note the path location in
>    the field labeled Android SDK Tools Installed with Unity (recommended)
> 4. Copy the Android Studio SDK to Unity Navigate to both paths in
>    explorer. In each there will be a folder called 'platforms'. Go into
>    this folder from the Android SDK path and copy the android-29 folder
>    to the platforms folder in the Unity path.
>
> Credit goes to this dude and the stack overflow post he credits that I
> can no longer find:

Comment: It's not working, I'm Using 2018 version. This folder does not exist.

Comment: It should be inside the folder where you installed your Unity Editor. Did you install Unity Editor through Unity Hub? Did you install Android Build Support through Unity Hub?

Comment: I installed unity in both ways, with Hub or without Hub. there are no differents. i download and installed unity 2018.3.9 and unity 2018.4.29 (the last version of unity 2018). But the "SDK folder" in ( C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.6f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\bin )  does not exists. @TrongNguyen